# Protect the unauthenticated route in next js

Tags: next.js

I'm newly start on next js project , we have added a middlewate in next js to protect the route like below

```
useEffect(() => {
if (typeof window !== undefined) {
  if (router.pathname == "/reset-password") {
    // allow before login
  }else if (!loginUser.authenticated) {
    router.push('./login')
  }
  else if (loginUser.authenticated && !loginUser.selectedCustomer) {
    router.push('./search-customer')
  } else if (loginUser.authenticated && loginUser.selectedCustomer) {
    if (router.pathname == "/") {
      router.push("/stock-items/categories");
    }
  }
}
```

}, []);
return <>{props.children}</>;

But the issue is when any one direclty hit the specific route the controller goes to specific page and then nevigate to login screen if user is not login

i'm trying to stop that type of process , if user is not login then then any route should not be nevigate

please help us

Answer (score 0):

[`useEffect`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect) runs on the client-side **after the DOM has rendered** (the `typeof window` check is therefore unnecessary).
This means any checks you place in the `useEffect` will be ran after the user see's the page (even just for a split second).

There are 2 options how you can handle this. Both are mentioned in the [**authentication guide**](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication) in NextJS docs. I recommend taking a look.

### [Option 1](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication#authenticating-statically-generated-pages)

Set loading state default state as `true`, rendering a loading indicator while you do your authentication checks...

After you finish authenticating, toggle the `loading` state to `false`, allowing to render the page.

### [Option 2](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication#authenticating-server-rendered-pages) (Recommended)

What you want to do here is take advantage of Next's core features such as [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props).
The code you put into `getServerSideProps` runs BEFORE the client receives any HTML payload.

In the `getServerSideProps` you can do your authentication, check for authentication cookie or `Authorization` header, depends what authentication method you use, and either redirect the user to `/login` page.

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, there is a specific way to handle authentication. You would need to store a cookie containing the authentication token, and then in your middleware, you can check if that cookie exists by matching the route. If the cookie does not exist, you can perform a redirect. This helps ensure that only authenticated users can access protected routes.

If you are implementing authentication, I would suggest using NextAuth.js. With NextAuth.js, you can use their different hooks and functions to protect both the server and client components of your application. Additionally, if you want to integrate third-party logins like Google or Facebook, NextAuth.js makes it relatively easy to do so. It provides built-in provider options for popular social authentication services, allowing you to quickly add them to your authentication flow.

you can check more details on  next-auth offical documentation.
https://next-auth.js.org/